# Create gap between div and form

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out how to get a gap between

```
    <div class="info">
        <p>Location:</p>
        <p>Dominion Theatre, W1T 7AQ</p>
    </div>
```

and

```
    <form>
        <label>Name (Required)
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
        </label>
    </form>
```

How would I go about doing it. I've tried using margin/padding without any luck?

**HTML**

```
<div class="bt fbCenter">
    <div class="fb">
        <div class="info">
            <p>Event Starts:</p>
            <p>25th December 2014 19:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Event Ends:</p>
            <p>25th December 2014 21:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Location:</p>
            <p>Dominion Theatre, W1T 7AQ</p>
        </div>
        <form>
            <label>Name (Required)
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.bt input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
.bt button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5em;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
}
.bt button:hover {
    background-color: #818181;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.fbCenter {
    text-align: center;
}
.bt .fb {
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    padding: 2em;
    color: #585858;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
}
.fb .info {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.fb p {
    float: left;
}
.fb p:nth-of-type(even) {
    width: 80%;
}
.fb p:nth-of-type(odd) {
    width: 20%;
}
.fb p.last {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2kkep4qs/).

Comment: did u try a <br/> or <hr> between the form and the div?

Comment: <br/> doesn't work but <hr> does

Comment: Does this not work? ` .fb .info:last {margin-bottom: 5em;}`?
Alternatively, add `margin-top:/*Some value for gap*/` to a class on the form itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be aware of margin collapsing and float collapsing.

Add a marging to the top of the from and clear the floats in the `info` divs

```
.fb form{
    margin-top:2em;}

.fb .info {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    clear:both;
}
```

```css
.fb form{
    margin-top:5em;}

.bt input {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.5em;
}
.bt button {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1.5em;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0;
}
.bt button:hover {
    background-color: #818181;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.fbCenter {
    text-align: center;
}
.bt .fb {
    border: 1px solid #818181;
    padding: 2em;
    color: #585858;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 75%;
}
.fb .info {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    clear:both;
}
.fb p {
    float: left;
}
.fb p:nth-of-type(even) {
    width: 80%;
}
.fb p:nth-of-type(odd) {
    width: 20%;
}
.fb p.last {
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="bt fbCenter">
    <div class="fb">
        <div class="info">
            <p>Event Starts:</p>
            <p>25th December 2014 19:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Event Ends:</p>
            <p>25th December 2014 21:00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <p>Location:</p>
            <p>Dominion Theatre, W1T 7AQ</p>
        </div>
        <form>
            <label>Name (Required)
                <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
            </label>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note that the margin on the top of the form needs to be bigger than the margin on the bottom of the `.info` class. This is due to Margin Collapsing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing & http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/collapsing-margins/)

You should probably also become familiar with [Clearfix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/), how it works, why and when it is needed.

I'm not a fan of `float` so here as an [alterate version](http://jsfiddle.net/k9shdpLo/) that utilises `display:table`, `display:table-row` and `display:table-cell`

Answer (score 1):

You could create another class to insert between both of them like this example http://jsfiddle.net/2kkep4qs/8/

HTML

```
<div class="info">
     <p>Location:</p>
     <p>Dominion Theatre, W1T 7AQ</p>
 </div>
 <div class="bt-space"></div>
 <form>
     <label>Name (Required)
         <input type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
     </label>
 </form>
```

CSS New class

```
.bt-space{padding:25px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do `<hr>` and color it white, or

you could always add an empty div between div and form:

```
<div class="info">
         &nbsp;
    </div>
```

Comment: Adding meaningless HTML is always a bad idea